# cURL with variables and multiprocessing in shell

Tags: bash, variables, curl, multiprocessing, output

I've been trying to solve this for a few days with no luck. What I am trying to do is to feed my curl json with my local IPs, process multiple cURLs as fast as possible in and receive variables back to a file.

My first code is running fine, but he is processing line by line and it is taking eternity. I would like to run something like xargs or parallel.

I have the following .txt file (IP.txt):

```
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.102
192.168.1.104
192.168.1.105
192.168.1.106
192.168.1.168
...
```

I am feeding this file to a code:

```
cat IP.txt | while read LINE; do

C_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"method":"data","params":[]}' $LINE:80 | jq -r '.result[]')

for F_RESPONSE in $C_RESPONSE; do
echo $LINE $F_RESPONSE >> output.txt

done
done
```

Output of this script is following:

```
192.168.1.100 value_1
192.168.1.100 value_2
192.168.1.100 value_3
192.168.1.100 value_4
192.168.1.100 value_5
192.168.1.102 value_1
192.168.1.102 value_2
192.168.1.102 value_3
192.168.1.104 value_1
192.168.1.104 value_2
192.168.1.104 value_3
192.168.1.104 value_4
192.168.1.104 value_5
192.168.1.104 value_6
192.168.1.104 value_7
192.168.1.104 value_8
192.168.1.104 value_9
192.168.1.104 value_10
192.168.1.105 value_1
192.168.1.105 value_2
192.168.1.106 value_1
192.168.1.168 value_1
...
```

I would like to make this code faster with parallel or xargs or even &. However adding &:

```
C_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"method":"data","params":[]}' $LINE:80 | jq -r '.result[]') &
```

I'm sending script to the background and I am unable to process

```
for F_RESPONSE in $C_RESPONSE; do
echo $LINE $F_RESPONSE >> output.txt
```

With parallel command like this I am able to produce only values but I can't see IP:

```
cat IP.txt | parallel -j200 "curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' {}:80 -X POST -d '{\"method\":\"data\",\"params\":[]}'" | jq -r '.result[]' >> output.txt

value_1
value_2
value_3
value_4
value_5
value_1
value_2
value_3
value_1
value_2
value_3
value_4
value_5
value_6
value_7
value_8
value_9
value_10
value_1
value_2
value_1
value_1
...
```

I've tried googling and reading many tutorials, but no luck. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

So here is a quick solution as proposed by @Poshi. Solution is without limiter so can cause problems if too many background jobs will be running.

```
#!/bin/bash

function call() {
    arg1=$1
    C_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"method":"data","params":[]}' $arg1:80 | jq -r '.result[]')

    for F_RESPONSE in $C_RESPONSE; do
    echo $arg1 $F_RESPONSE >> output.txt
done
}

cat IP.txt | while read LINE; do

call $LINE &

done
```

Comment: Maybe you can encapsulate the cURL+postprocessing in a function, and send that function into background. That way you will be able to process the results and you won't have to resort to more complicated tools than the standard bash job management.

Comment: Thank you very much for great advise! It worked as desired. #!/bin/bash

function call() {  
 arg1=$1  
 C_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"method":"data","params":[]}' $arg1:80 | jq -r '.result[]')

 for F_RESPONSE in $C_RESPONSE; do
 echo $arg1 $F_RESPONSE >> output.txt
done
}

cat IP.txt | while read LINE; do

call $LINE &

done

Comment: the quick solution is not efficient, It may cause severe performance issues if you do not limit number of running background processes for your curl script

Comment: @Simonare you are right, already killed my machine with that. Need to add some kind of limiter. Any ideas?

Comment: I added an answer for you, please check

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) are pertinent.

Comment: BTW, all-caps variables are in reserved namespace -- you should use lower-case names for variables you define. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that environment and shell variables share a namespace (setting the latter will overwrite the former when names clash).

Comment: As another aside, putting `>>output.txt` or your individual `echo` lines is crazy inefficient, because it reopens the output file every time it needs to just to write one line, and closes it and flushes it after each line. Much better to open the handle just once and reuse it, as by putting `>output.txt` after the `done` to redirect stdout for the whole loop.

Comment: I am aware >>output.txt is not the most elegant solution, however I am constantly working with that file with another script and I would like to read it as much up to date as possible. Don't know solution other than >>

Comment: `echo` still `write()`s, making content visible to the VFS layer and thus to other processes; it just doesn't force more of a flush than that (so it doesn't force the inode to be updated with a new mtime, f/e). Which is to say, I *gave* you a solution, two comments ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

as an improvement to your code, you may consider to add control for number of processes initialized. check my answer below

```
#!/bin/bash

function call() {
    arg1=$1
    C_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"method":"data","params":[]}' $arg1:80 | jq -r '.result[]')

    for F_RESPONSE in $C_RESPONSE; do
    echo $arg1 $F_RESPONSE >> output.txt
done
}

cat IP.txt | while read LINE; do

while (($(pgrep -P "$$" curl | wc -l)> 10))
do
    sleep 0,2;
done

call $LINE &

done
```

Comment: With code as is I am getting start.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
start.sh: line 19: `done'. So after little tweak while($(pgrep init | wc -l)> 10); do and done at the end I'm getting start.sh: line 14: 0: command not found. Not completely sure what it is because I do have pgrep and wc installed and I am able to call them from console with pgrep --help and wc --help

Comment: the init part is needed to be changed to curl

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: You realize that `[[ 2 > 10 ]]` is true? You can't use `>` in `[[ ]]` for comparing numbers safely; switch to either `(( ))` or `-gt`.

Comment: improved thank you :)

Comment: `pgrep curl` is pretty messy -- you're counting *all* `curl` instances, not just the ones started by the same script. At least make it `pgrep -P "$$" curl`, so it's limited to `curl` instances started by the current bash instance.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs -P` is a tool built for the job. (GNU parallel even moreso, but it's a mess of perl with semantics that make its use fault-prone so I cannot recommend its use; see the mailing list thread at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2015-05/msg00005.html).

```
call() {
  : # put your definition here
}
export -f call # make that function accessible to child processes

# tell xargs to start 4 shells (adjust to taste!) processing lines.
# presently, this gives each shell 16 jobs to reduce startup overhead
# ...adjust to tune for your actual workload.
<IP.txt xargs -n 16 -d $'\n' -P4 bash -c 'for line; call "$line"; done' _
```

Comment: I'd like to ask if you know which solution is faster. Or if there is any way to run some kind of benchmark on both solutions. To stick up with bash loop and function or use xargs. I'd like to make it as snappy as possible on regular machine like i7 16GB on local network where internet speed is really not a limitation. Without using python or java or c. I can do "something" in bash only at this moment.

Comment: On a system where internet speed isn't a limitation, you'll want a much larger value than `-P4`. Maybe start with `-P16`, measure throughput, and tune from there? This is certainly going to be lower-latency than the shell-loop hack -- you don't need any equivalent to the `sleep 0.2` it uses when you're waiting for `SIGCHILD` events to provide immediate notice when a subprocess exits (whereas if you took out that `sleep` call, the other answer would be spinning its wheels running `pgrep` over and over and over, which waiting for an actual affirmative notice from the OS avoids).

Comment: ...also, if your list of IPs is fairly short, you'll be better off with a lower `-n` value; if it's long, it doesn't make much of a difference.